# How to retrieve all contents of a file from file_get_contents through PHP?

Tags: php, variables, echo, file-get-contents

I am trying to work out how to retrieve all of the contents of a text file as a string and store it in a variable through PHP.

The code below works fine through `file_get_contents` and the PHP code is sent to the `$get` variable correctly, however, it doesn't get displayed on `index.php` correctly.

The `index.php` file will echo out `hi` rather than just `hi`.

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $display = "hello";
    $get = file_get_contents("get.txt");
    echo $get;
?>
```

**get.txt**

```
hi, $display;
```

How would I go about fixing this? I would really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: it would work if you used `include('get.php')` -- and `hi $display` was in `get.php`

Comment: `file_get_contents()` just reads the content of the file, it doesn't parse it as PHP

Comment: Your question is inconsistent, though. You say that it prints out `<?php echo "hi" ?>` and then you say that your file contains: `hi, $display`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index.php:

```
<?php
   echo 'hi';
?>
```

some.php:

```
<?php
    require 'index.php';
?>
```

Will be shown text `hi`.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the webserver is not processing the PHP code.  If you are working locally(from your computer) then you need server software running on that machine for PHP code (HTML, CSS, and Javascript will run fine).  If that's the case get a program like "WAMP Server" and you'll be good to go with PHP.

Comment: Considering that the `index.php` file is getting parsed, it's kind of safe to assume that the OP has PHP installed. The problem is that the OP is using `file_get_contents()`, which doesn't parse the source file, but rather get's read as an ordinary string.